# Proof of Bertini Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne's proof of the Bertini Theorem (II, Thm. 8.18) he shows that the set $B_x$ is a linear system of dimension $n-r-1$ and uses this fact to conclude that the set $B$ is irreducible. However I don't see how this would work if $\dim X = n-1$ since then $B_x$ would have dimension $0$. I would be very happy for some hints as to why this is not a problem in this case.

Comment: Why do you think this would be a problem? [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579527/use-irreducible-fibers-to-show-x-is-irreducible) shows that a proper morphism to an irreducible variety with nonempty irreducible equidimensional fibers implies the source is irreducible. That's exactly this situation.

Comment: In some other proof, they handled the case $r = n-1$ separately and claimed that then $U = \check{\mathbb{P}^n} \setminus X_{\text{dual}}$, so I thought that was what you had to do. But I guess I just didn’t think about the fact that being $0$-dimensional is no problem for irreducibility